# Maildir++ quota does not count Trash

Tags: postfix, quota, email

I have dicovered that standard quota implementation on maildir++ operated by maildrop and courier-imap (installed on ubuntu machine) does not count mails in a .Trash directory.

Users now have almost unlimited mail space. Is there any option to disable this bad behavior without recompiling maildrop and imap packages?

If not, how i can do this on ubuntu 12.10?

**Edit:**

ive recompiled maildrop and courier-imap packages with

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="--with-trashquota" fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

and nothing changes, trash is still unlimited.

**Edit2:**

More information according to `mr.spuratic` question in comments:

- User information are stored in a PostgreSQL database.
- Yes, all users has `maildirsize` in their maildirs, and quota is working (webmail and thunderbird shows right values)
- Yes, im using maildrop

Comment: Did you blow away the `maildirsize` cache files too? The contents of that may be stale, delete it for a test user then it will be recreated with (hopefully) the correct usage calculation.

Comment: yes, deleted old and recreated - trash still unlimited

Comment: `maildrop -v` won't confirm the option, so run this against **unstripped** binaries, `make install` likely stripped them so you'll need to find the build dir, then: `nm --size-sort ./maildrop/maildrop | fgrep maildirquota_count`. If the symbols sizes are low (<20) then `--with-trashquota` is enabled (those functions do nothing in that case). You did re-install, and restart `imapd`, and both the `maildrop` and `imapd` binaries are definitely the new ones?

Comment: I did not `make install`, command in my question produced *.deb files which i have installed and rebooted whole system. Result of `nm` that you posted is this: `000000a3 T maildirquota_countfile
000000a5 T maildirquota_countfolder`

Comment: OK, trashquota is definitely enabled in that binary then... Are you using a local userdb or LDAP? Do all users have a `maildirsize` file in their maildir? Is quota working as expected otherwise? You are using postfix with `maildrop` as an MDA, and **not** postfix native maildir delivery? see http://www.postfix.org/MAILDROP_README.html .

Comment: please look at updated question.

Comment: Sorry, more questions :) Which webmail SqWebmail or something else via IMAP? If it's something that accesses the maildirs directly like SqWebmail then that needs a recompile too. The problem ought not be observed with strictly Thunderbird only users in that case.

Comment: own webmail client which connects via imap.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7317/discussion-between-mr-spuratic-and-wombat)

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The reason is that otherwise you really easily end up with a situation where people can't delete their mails anymore when the quota is reached, as MUAs often don't just *delete* mails, but instead use the following mechanism:

- Copy mail to `.trash`
- mark copied mail as `\deleted`
- expunge from original mailbox
- maybe empty the `.trash` at some point, on user request, program exit or never.

If `.trash` is considered for quotas, this will fail.

[This page](http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/README.maildirquota.html) gives some hints about how to change this behaviour for Courier.

Comment: Well, so its a bad design for me. Mail will be accessed only by our own webmail which handles situations like that. So i guess i need to recompile packages, but how...